# Equivalent of await(x==0) in Java

Tags: java, concurrency, pthreads, semaphore

In for example Pthreads there is a possibility to have a process wait for a certain condition, for example:

```
<await (nr == 0 ^ nw == 0) nw++>;
```

Is there a way to do this in a similar way using Semaphores in Java? Waiting for a condition like nr==0 that is.

Comment: I partially fixed the formatting of your code snippet so it's at least visible; please edit to make it correct if necessary.

Comment: Have a look at Condition interface : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html

Comment: I think a Condition will work, but woulnd't I manually have to check every now and then from another thread and then signal through the condition?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it is a one-off event, you could use [a `CountDownLatch`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html):

```
private final CountDownLatch xIsZeroLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);
```

You then use it as follows:

- in your waiting thread:

  ```
  xIsZeroLatch.await();
  ```
- in the other thread(s):

  ```
  x = newX();
  if (x == 0) xIsZeroLatch.countDown();
  ```

If the condition can change several times between true and false and each change requires an event, you can use a `Semaphore` with one permit.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void setX(int a) {
    x = a;
    if(x==0) {
         //do stuff
    }
}
```

Then use that setter instead of `x = a`.

Comment: If several threads are involved, you should probably introduce some form of synchronization.